# How to adjust code from python 3.5 to 3.7, appending Stock Data into master file

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to coding python and I'm absolutely loving it! Unfortunately my limited knowledge in it has made me hit a roadblock with a piece of code from a tutorial I have been following, see link below:

https://pythonprogramming.net/combining-stock-prices-into-one-dataframe-python-programming-for-finance/?completed=/sp500-company-price-data-python-programming-for-finance/

### Quick summary of what i'm trying to do:

1) Copy ticker list from wikipedia of all SP500 companies using bs4 (**DONE**)

2) Get data from Yahoo on all Tickers using *pandas_datareader* and Import all SP500 companies with OHLC data individually in csv files in a folder (called **stock_dfs**)  (**DONE-ish**)

*Yahoo kinda blocks me after bout 70 of them... a recommendation would be great!... i've tried importing **time** and using  `time.sleep` to create a 5 second delay but no matter where i place it in the loop Yahoo cuts me off..*

3) Combine all Ticker data into one master file ready to be analyzed... I just can't combine them. I even tried creating the csv manually but still nothing.

**Note**: in the code on the website he is calling for *morningstar* data instead of *yahoo*.. on the video he puts yahoo.. i think this was done in error. Either way when he runs it, it works on 3.5. So i *assume* it's a version issue.

Thanks in advance!

Below you will find the error messages i get when running this as well as the block of code right afterwards.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/harry/PycharmProjects/Tutorials/Finance with Python/SENTDEX_T7_sp500InOneDataframe.py", line 87, in <module>
    compile_data()
  File "C:/Users/harry/PycharmProjects/Tutorials/Finance with Python/SENTDEX_T7_sp500InOneDataframe.py", line 70, in compile_data
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
  File "C:\Users\harry\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\harry\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\harry\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\harry\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\harry\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'stock_dfs/BRK.B.csv' does not exist: b'stock_dfs/BRK.B.csv'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests


def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    return tickers


# save_sp500_tickers()
def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime.now()
    for ticker in tickers:
        # just in case your connection breaks, we'd like to save our progress!
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.reset_index(inplace=True)
            df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
            df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))


def compile_data():
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
        df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

        df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

        if count % 10 == 0:
            print(count)
    print(main_df.head())
    main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')


compile_data()
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError` is a key piece here. The problem is that either the path is wrong or your file is not located where you think it is.

Comment: From my understanding it's reading/writing in the same directory, all other operations worked fine when you run it block by block. I appreciate your help, thanks! I'll keep at it, eventually i will figure it out and post the answer here if someone doesn't beat me to it